# Application gateway ingress controller in updating state

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-gateway

Deployed an Application gateway Ingress controller in uat environment. The Application gateway is continuously in the updating state. It shows unhealthy state with the Kubernetes service. The screenshot is as attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efvdl.png)

The screenshot for the application gateway status is also hereby attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npCNS.png)

Comment: its telling you that the readyness probe failed even one the kube system. Maybe you have some network policy issues

Comment: you use a AKS or VM ? please provide more details

Comment: AKS @QuentinMerlin

Comment: Hello @Syed, As per the first image the error is occuring as the application gateway is in updating state and the kubernetes is failing to get the liveness/readiness probe. Can you try to stop the application gateway and then start again to see if the issue resolves??